# HTTP request cannot get the contact photo using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

If I use the library @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client, I can get the contact photo as binary data, convert it to base64 and get the correct photo with the code below:

```
    const request = require('request')
    const microsoftGraph = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');

    let token = token-value
    let client = getMicrosoftGrapClient(token);
    let id = contact-id;
    let url = '/me/contacts/' + id + '/photo/$value';

                client.api(url).get().then((res) => {
                    //console.log(res);
                    var encodedImage = new Buffer(res, 'binary').toString('base64');
                    console.log("encodedImage>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
                    console.log (encodedImage);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });;

    function getMicrosoftGrapClient (token) {
        // Create a Graph client
            return microsoftGraph.Client.init({
            authProvider: (done) => {
            // Just return the token
            done(null, token);
            }});
    }
```

I cannot get the correct contact photo with the HTTP GET. The HTTP
    response code is 200 but the body is not the binary data of photo.
    Please let me know what the error is. Here is the code:

```
const request = require('request')

request({ 

    url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/{contact_id}/photo/$value",

    method: 'GET',

    headers: {
        'content-type': 'image/jpg',  
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'
    }

 }, function (error, response, body){

    console.log(error);

    var encodedImage = new Buffer(body, 'binary').toString('base64');

    console.log(encodedImage);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

*Encoding* needs to be explicitly specified as

```
 encoding: null
```

In that case the body will be of type `Buffer`, instead of the default (`string`).

And `content-type` could be omitted.

Example

```
request({
        url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value",
        method: 'GET',
        encoding: null,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        var encImage = new Buffer(body, 'binary');
        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, encImage );
    });
```